# Fans really loud, ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, fan, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I've been trying to get into using Ubuntu 12.10, but it's hard when my PCs fans are nonstop running so loud I get a headache at the very least.

While it was running Windows 7 the fans were mostly quiet. I've tried all these vague guides to using lm-sensors and fancontrol but so far all that has achieved is pwmconfig increasing the speed of one fan to max and then not lowering it until I restart no matter what I blindly attempt.

All I want to do is lower the PWM/RPM.

EDIT: I managed to make just the rear fan slow down drastically. Thankfully it's the largest and loudest fan, so even if I can't get the others to slow it's a decent victory.

Comment: What is the output of this Terminal command: **lspci | grep VGA**

Comment: 05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] (rev a1)

Answer (score 0):

**Did you install the proprietary display driver?**
As I think, the fans are on fire because the temperature of your video card is bit higher than usual.
Installing the display driver provided by Nvidia should fix the problem.
Run this command in Terminal:

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: After restarting that has broken the OS. After logging in I'm just given the wallpaper and my cursor, and when I attempt to shutdown it fails to terminate all processes normally.

Comment: Sorry about that. You will have to remove it then. **sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current**

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll keep playing around with fancontrol for now, I think I may have found the issue and I'll answer myself if I figure it out.